# K-Meleon fails to load pages that use SSL

Tags: browser, ssl

I recently downloaded K-Meleon however when attempting to browse pages or sites that use SSL, I am presented with a page that reads as attached.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to resolve it. For those unaware when defining proxy settings you need to hit or click on apply when setting proxy settings. If not they do not take effect.